# Python generator block indefinitely after generating a discrete number of elements

Tags: python, generator, grpc

Fairly new to Python, so my apologies if I've missed something completely obvious.

I have the need for a generator that will yield a small number of elements after which it will block indefinitely.  This is necessary in order to work around a 'feature' of gRPC-py that will close the client send channel after sending all of the elements generated by the generator.

Any thoughts on how to approach this, if even possible?

Comment: Could you update the question with the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Finally figured this out using Threading conditions to simulate a count down latch.